# What is a good power electronics textbook?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I really want to learn as much as I can about power electronics, switching mode power supplies, and overall analog design.  Unfortunately my universities computer engineering program is still relatively new and does not have these specific courses.

I have looked over the ones on amazon but I really just feel like I can't trust the review there.

If I may pull from the large amount of experience here, what would be a good power supply text book to learn these fundamentals?

Comment: Very few in universities in the US have a solid power electronics program.  The only ones that I'm aware of are: University of Colorado, University of West Virginia [iirc], Cal Poly in San Luis Obispo.

Comment: Yea, well its an old field.  While I've worked with switching-mode power supplies in great-depth, I feel like I don't have a good fundamentals reference or knowledge (I could be wrong) but I still want to get very solid at this. 
I'm surprised that we don't have more than basics circuits in regards to analog circuits.

Comment: Power electronics is a relatively small field (in terms of head count) and it's harder to teach, compared to small signal vanilla EECS.  These 2 factors make power electronics programs less attractive for students to take and for universities to teach.  In the last 5 years or so, the interest to power electronics has been somewhat coming back due to growing interest in electric vehicles, greener energy, data centers.

Comment: I can entirely understand the increased difficulty.  I understand digital systems very very well and I have worked with analog concepts in conjunction w/ digital systems although I don't understand it quite to the same caliber

Comment: AFAIK, the standard undergrad text book for power electronics is [Power Electronics: Converters, Applications, and Design](http://www.amazon.com/Power-Electronics-Converters-Applications-Design/dp/0471226939) by Ned Mohan et al.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Books I've found useful for power electronics:

```
Transformer and Inductor Design Handbook, McLyman

Switching Power Supply Design, Pressman

Switchmode Power Supply Handbook, Billings

Switching Power Supply Design and Optimization, Maniktala
```

Answer (score 6):

Coursera is starting a Power electronics course shortly

https://www.coursera.org/course/powerelectronics

that might be applicable. CU seems to have one of the few power electronics concentrations that I've seen.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend the following textbooks.

1. Power electronics: converters, applications, and design by Ned Mohan and Tore M. Undeland
2. POWER ELECTRONICS: ESSENTIALS & APPLICATIONS (With CD ) by L. Umanand
3. Power Electronics by Daniel W.Hart ( one of the best books for understanding the concepts of power supplies)